# Cannot Update. Database or object is read-only error 3027

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have 2 tables and from them I do a query called "Query_Dates". There, I created 4 calculated fields which compares fields of the two tables previously mentioned. 
What I am trying to do is everytime the calculated fields are equal to "Diff", gets the value from the second table (ADHOC) and and puts it in the 1st table (Master_Table). In total there are 4 fields I would change depending on other 4 fields called (CheckRR, CheckQual, CheckProd, CheckCap).

The problem is that it gives me an error 3027, object is read-only in line where it is showed "rsd.edit" . Could anybody help me or give me any feedback?. Thank you in advance.

Below, you can find the code.

```
enter code here
Private Sub Comando27_Click()

Dim rsd As DAO.Recordset

Dim supplierName As String

Set rsd = Application.CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Query_Dates", dbOpenDynaset)

retry: supplierName = InputBox("Please enter the Supplier Name", _
"Information Required")

'MsgBox "Supplier requested: " & supplierName

valid = MsgBox("Supplier Requested = " & supplierName & "??", vbYesNoCancel, "Validation")

If valid = 7 Then

GoTo retry

ElseIf valid = 2 Then

GoTo salir

End If

rsd.MoveFirst

Do While Not rsd.EOF

If rsd![Supplier Name] = supplierName Then

If rsd![CheckRR] = "Diff" And rsd![ADHOC_Run at Rate Dt] <> Empty Then

rsd.Edit

rsd![Run at Rate Dt] = rsd![ADHOC_Run at Rate Dt]

rsd.Update

End If

If rsd![CheckQual] = "Diff" And rsd![ADHOC_Qual Verif Dt] <> Empty Then

rsd.Edit

rsd![Master_Table_Qual Verif Dt] = rsd![ADHOC_Qual Verif Dt]

rsd.Update

End If

If rsd![CheckProd] = "Diff" And rsd![ADHOC_Prod Verif Dt] <> Empty Then

rst.Edit

rsd![Master_Table_Prod Verif Dt] = rsd![ADHOC_Prod Verif Dt]

rsd.Update

End If

If rsd![CheckCap] = "Diff" And rsd![ADHOC_Prod Verif Dt] <> Empty Then

rsd.Edit

rsd![Master_Table_Cap Verif Dt] = rsd![ADHOC_Cap Verif Dt]

rsd.Update

End If

End If

rsd.MoveNext

Loop

salir: rsd.Close

Set rsd = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Some queries aren't updatable. Check the [Updatable property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff192110.aspx) before trying to edit.

```
if rsd.Updatable then
```

But you might have a bigger problem. Your declaration doesn't match your usage.

```
Dim rsd As DAO.Recordset
...
If rsd![CheckProd] = "Diff" And rsd![ADHOC_Prod Verif Dt] <> Empty Then

rst.Edit
```

See the difference? Declared rsd, used rst.Edit. Either you've declared rst in an outer scope--a Bad Thing--or you're not using `Option Explicit`--also a Bad Thing.